# Scan and send scanned image to desktop by WiFi

Tags: wireless, printing, scanner

Using a Canon ST5051 with Wifi on an Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit PC. Printing is a cinch, but sending an scanned image to the desktop fails.

Appreciate any help please

Comment: Do you know the ip address of the printer? assuming 192.168.1.nn enter the address into your browser and that might give you more options by addressing the printer directly.

Comment: Thanks Graham I will tty that now.

Comment: DId you mean to type you are using the Canon Pixma TS5051 multifunction device https://www.canon.ie/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts5051.html I? f so, please click [edit] and revise your question. Please also tell us how it fails; are there any error messages? According to the instructions you are following, what should happen which does not?  What is the web link for those instructions? Please do not click Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].